# Why the timer1 never start?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
Video objects = null;
        private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {
            stringProgressReport[0] = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 0);
            timer1.Start();
            objects = obj;
        }
```

This event i register it in the Upload method where i upload a video file to youtube.
Using a break point i see it's getting ot the lines in the event i also see on UploadStatus the string "Uploaded"

This is the upload method:

```
 static Video video = null;

        private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\bin\Debug\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
                }
                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
                });
                video = new Video();
                video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
                video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
                video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
                video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
                /*upload.comboBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "Gaming";// (upload.comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
                }));*/
                video.Status = new VideoStatus();
                video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {

                    const int KB = 0x400;
                    var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                        "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                    // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
                    videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
                    dt = DateTime.Now;
                    videosInsertRequest.Upload();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        string status = video.Status.UploadStatus;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                string errorss = errors.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Now i'm using a timer to check for the progress of the video file processing.
But the timer1 tick event is not getting to there.

I used a break point and it's getting to the line timer1.Start();
But i also added a break point on the timer1 tick event and it's never get there.

```
    string fff = "";
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        fff = objects.ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus;
    }
```

I tried timer1.Enabled = true; and now timer1.Start(); but it's not getting to the tick event.

The timer1 is in my form designer.

Comment: Make sure that the event handler `timer1_Tick` is attached correctly.

Comment: Which interval is set for your timer?

Comment: My crystal ball says that this method runs on a worker thread.  Not good.  That ReportProgress() call doesn't seem to do anything interesting, you found a better use for it.

Comment: Habib attached fine. Intervel was 10000 now for testing changed to 100 not working. Hans i did that it will not use any of the lines in the event but the timer1.Start(); still it's not getting to the timer tick event. Also updated my question added the upload method to youtube i'm using to upload videos in this method i register to the videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived event. In this even i know when the file is uploaded but now i want to check in real time the file process progress to see the status of the process checking every 10 seconds for example untill file processed.

Comment: Is that `while (true) {}` potentially blocking your code?

Comment: Removed it. In the end what helped is using Timers instead the Timer of the winforms in the designer.

Comment: This all the time null: fff = objects.ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus; the part ProcessingDetials and ProcessingStatus is null all the time i'm checking every 10 seconds. How can i check the video file processing progress ?